# How to configure aws in order to get log events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-vpc, aws-cli, netflow

My question has two parts:
- How to get log events?   The command line tells me that I need to configure aws... 
- How to configure aws?

I try to get log events by doing the following:

```
sudo aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name my-group --log-stream-name my-stream --region us-west-2
```

But I get the error `Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".`

So, that is exactly what I do.  I run `aws configure`, and I fill in the fields as appropriate:

```
AWS Access Key ID [****************NEEA]: 
AWS Secret Access Key [****************Ta1a]: 
Default region name [us-west-2]: 
Default output format [json]:
```

Howevever, I try again to get log events: 
`sudo aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name my-group --log-stream-name my-stream --region us-west-2`, and the same error results.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your snippets, you are running the [AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI)](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) via `sudo`, i.e.:

```
sudo aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name my-group --log-stream-name my-stream --region us-west-2
```

However, you seem to [configure the AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) itself without using `sudo`, i.e. just:

```
aws configure
```

This will store the credentials in the current users home directory, rather than the one of the root user - accordingly, you can fix this by either running the actual `aws logs` commands without `sudo` too, or configure AWS credentials for the root user as well, e.g.:

```
sudo aws configure
```